# How to compress nested "if else" statements in processing?

Tags: processing

i have a long script that lets a user choose a team once they enter a set of characters. it goes through a long list of if else statements in order to choose it. are there any other commands that would be more fitting? Here is my current code:

```
 if (finalChar.equals("aa") == true) {
r = 151;
g = 35;
b = 63;
title = "Arizona Cardinals Time!";
imageSelected = "cardinals";
} else {
if (finalChar.equals("ab") == true) {
r = 151;
g = 35;
b = 63;
title = "Atlanta Falcons Time!";
imageSelected = "falcons";
} else {
if (finalChar.equals("ac") == true) {
r = 26;
g = 25;
b = 95;
title = "Baltimore Ravens Time!";
imageSelected = "ravens";
} else {
if (finalChar.equals("ad") == true) {
r = 0;
g = 51;
b = 141;
rh = 198;
gh = 12;
bh = 48;
title = "Buffalo Bills Time!";
imageSelected = "bills";
} else {
if (finalChar.equals("ae") == true) {
r = 0;
g = 133;
b = 202;
        rh = 16;
        gh = 24;
        bh = 32;
        title = "Carolina Panthers Time!";
        imageSelected = "panthers";
      } else {
        if (finalChar.equals("af") == true) {
          r = 11;
          g = 22;
          b = 42;
          rh = 200;
          gh = 56;
          bh = 3;
          title = "Chicago Bears Time!";
          imageSelected = "bears";
        } else {
          if (finalChar.equals("ag") == true) {
            r = 251;
            g = 79;
            b = 20;
            rh = 0;
            gh = 0;
            bh = 0;
            title = "Cincinnati Bengals Time!";
            imageSelected = "bengals";
          } else {
            if (finalChar.equals("ah") == true) {
              r = 49;
              g = 29;
              b = 0;
              rh = 255;
              gh = 60;
              bh = 0;
              title = "Cleveland Browns Time!";
              imageSelected = "browns";
            } else {
              if (finalChar.equals("ai") == true) {
                r = 0;
                g = 34;
                b = 68;
                title = "Dallas Cowboys Time!";
                imageSelected = "cowboys";
              } else {
```

any help will be appreciated

i forgot to mention, but the code continues to go on, and it repeats over and over about 30 more times. sorry lol

Comment: 1) You can probably use `else if`, without opening another block (the `{`); 2) Can your language `switch` on strings?

Comment: One simple thing you can do that will greatly improve your code is using **proper indentation**.

Comment: 3) do you really need `== true` (in other words, would `if (finalChar.equals("ae"))` work?

Answer (score 1):

1. look into [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
2. learn how to [use an array](https://processing.org/reference/Array.html) of Strings
3. learn how to [do a for loop](https://processing.org/reference/for.html) to iterate through each String in your array and check your condition

e.g.

```
String[] suffixes = {"aa","ab","ac","ad","ae","af","ag","ah","ai"};
for(int i = 0 ; i < suffixes.length; i++){
 println(suffixes[i]); 
}
```

Depending on what you need to do with these strings bare in mind Processing also has a [String Dictionary](https://processing.org/reference/StringDict.html) which would allow you to associate one string with another String. 
(If you search through a list of Strings this may be more efficient than looping and comparing)

Be sure to go through arrays and loops which will come in handy if you choose to use a different structure for your data.

For example you could represent it as a [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_json.asp) object (which Processing supports via [JSONObject](https://processing.org/reference/JSONObject.html)):

```
{
  "aa": {
    "r" : 151,
    "g" : 35,
    "b" : 63,
    "title" : "Arizona Cardinals Time!",
    "imageSelected" : "cardinals"
  },
  "ab": {
    "r" : 151,
    "g" : 35,
    "b" : 63,
    "title" : "Atlanta Falcons Time!",
    "imageSelected" : "falcons"
  },
  "ac": {
    "r" : 26,
    "g" : 25,
    "b" : 95,
    "title" : "Baltimore Ravens Time!",
    "imageSelected" : "ravens"
  }
}
```

...etc.